# Sorting a file containing line delimiters

Tags: bash, sorting, field, delimiter

I have a text file looking like

```
text_a_3   xxx   yyy
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_b_2   xyx   zyz
- - - - - - - - - - - 
text_b_3   xxy   zyy
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_a_2   foo   bar
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_a_1   foo   bla
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_b_1   bla   bla
```

I want to sort this file numerically, based on the first field, so that my output would look like:

```
text_a_1   foo   bla
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_a_2   foo   bar
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_a_3   xxx   yyy
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_b_1   bla   bla 
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_b_2   xyx   zyz
- - - - - - - - - - - 
text_b_3   xxy   zyy
```

I thought *sort* would do the job. I thus tried

```
sort -n name_of_my_file
sort -k1 -n name_of_my_file
```

But it gives

```
- - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - -
text_a_1   foo   bla
text_a_2   foo   bar
text_a_3   xxx   yyy
text_b_1   bla   bla 
text_b_2   xyx   zyz
text_b_3   xxy   zyy
```

The option *--field-separator* is not of any help.

Is there any way to achieve this with a one-line, sort based command ?
Or is the only solution to extract text containing lines, sort them, and insert line delimiters afterwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk only, and relying with internal sort function `asort()` and record separator set to dashes line:

```
awk -v RS='- - - - - - - - - - -\n' '
  {a[++c]=$0}
  END{
    asort(a)
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++) 
      printf "%s%s",a[i],(i==c?"":RS)
  }' name_of_my_file
```

The script first fills the content of the input file into the array `a`. When the file is read, the array is sorted and then printed with the same input record separator.

Comment: I like this one, even though I fail to understand the meaning of (i==c?"":RS)

Comment: @EdouardIFP That's the standard `if ... then ... else ...` statement in a condensed way. I.e. the record separator is printed only if not the last record.

Answer (score 1):

When the line delimiters are all on the even lines, you can use

```
paste -d'\r' - - < yourfile | sort -n | tr '\r' '\n'
```

I actually prefer removing the delimiters in front, sort and add them afterwards, so please reconsider your requirements:

```
grep -Ev "(- )*-" yourfile | sort -n | sed 's/$/\n- - - - - - - - - - -/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `sort` + `awk` may help you.

```
sort -t"_" -k2 -k3 Input_file | awk '/^-/ && !val{val=$0} !/^-/{if(prev){print prev ORS val};prev=$0} END{print prev}'
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
sort -t"_" -k2 -k3  Input_file |
awk '
/^-/ && !val{
  val=$0}
!/^-/{
  if(prev){
    print prev ORS val};
  prev=$0
}
END{
  print prev
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I don't understand why I should set "_" as a field separator ?

Comment: @EdouardIFP, if we don't then by default space will be the delimiter and then results will be different.